# How to get Spring Boot to create a bean validator before creating all the other beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I'm trying to add a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to an existing Spring Boot web application.

No matter what I have tried (listed in a moment) it only creates the validator after most other beans (verified with both logging and breakpoints), so they never get validated.

Tangentially, I have hibernate-validator on the classpath and am attempting to use javax.validation.constraints on my `@Component` properties.

Application class has `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan({"my.package.**"})`.

- Adding an application.xml with the bean `<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>`
- Adding the above bean to validator.xml and adding `@ImportResource("validator.xml")`
- Adding a new `@Bean` to the Application class. `public Validator validator() { return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean(); }`
- Adding `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` to the above `@Bean`
- Adding a [BeanValidator](http://blog.trifork.com/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/) `@Component` to the scanned packages.
- And adding `@Order` to it.

In all cases, the validator is loaded only after FilterRegistrationBean has finished logging its business, but the beans I want to validate have already been created and used in setting up data connections and security for example.

Its been a few years since I've used Spring, but I don't remember these problems when defining everything in an application.xml. Is this just something that spring-boot doesn't support and I should move back to traditional Spring application config?

How can I get it to validate all my beans?

Comment: afaik only adding a validator isn't going to help you regardless how early it would be instantiated (unless it would be for the `@ConfigurationProperties` for Spring Boot that has support for it and which executes early in the process so there is already an instance for you) but it doesn't validate `@Component` beans.

Comment: Values are currently set from yaml if that is relevant. Using @Value so defaults can be provided.

Comment: That still isn't going to have them validated, afaik it only work for spring boot in `@ConfigurationProperties` not for other beans. Nor do I recall something like that to have ever been available...

Comment: But it works generally with normal Spring apps right?

Comment: No not that i'm aware of, at least not for validating beans in the application context. It works for hibernate entities and web mvc. Not for arbitrary beans in the application context. In 13 years of spring I never saw something like that without custom `BeanPostProcessor`s to work. So no it never worked out-of-the-box like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to make a `BeanValidationPostProcessor`.